# SQL Server stored procedure type: Insert, Delete, Update, or Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm doing some queries on SQL Server 2012 on the `sys.procedures` where I can see all my stored procedures from my database.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.PROCEDURES
```

I found some definition on

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES
```

Is there any column on the sys tables, or something that tells me if the stored procedure is a type: select, insert, delete, or update?

Comment: No because a single stored procedure can do all of those things or none of those things or some of those things based on non-deterministic conditions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question NO, there is no 1 column to let you know about that as others have mentioned, but you can probably use something like this to give you a rough idea... again this is not 100% correct

```
select sm.definition,
CASE WHEN
    sm.definition like '%SELECT%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'HasSelect',
CASE WHEN
    sm.definition like '%Insert into%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'HasInsert',
    CASE WHEN
    sm.definition like '%UPDATE TABLE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'HasUpdate',
    CASE WHEN
    sm.definition like '%DELETE FROM%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'HasDelete',
        CASE WHEN
    sm.definition like '%Drop%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'HasDrop'
FROM sys.procedures p
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules sm
ON p.object_id = sm.object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a column.  Because your procedure can do all of these things it's not useful to try and come up a column that serves that need.  But you can put those criteria into a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
  JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE o.name Like '%INSERT%'
    OR o.name Like '%SELECT%';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the metadata that will tell you what the stored procedure does.
Stored procedures do not have a "type", a single stored procedure could insert, update, delete and select all many times in the same procedure

If you're interested in something along those lines I suggest naming the procedures to include the metadata, like InsertSalesRecord or DeleteMonthlyInventory

Answer (score 0):

No. A stored procedure could held many insert, update, delete or select statements. It even could just add two numbers without any database operation.